# How to Connect CloverETL to Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloveretl

I am using CloverETL Designer for ETL operations and I want to load some csv files from GCS to my Clover graph. I used FlatFileReader and tried to get file using remote File URL but it is not working. Can someone please detail the entire process here??

The path for file in GCS is

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/PATH/Write_to_a_file.csv
```

And I need to get this csv file into the FlatFileReader in CloverETL Designer

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [Google Cloud Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-object-download) to GET the file; Clover's `HTTPConnector` component will allow you to pass in the appropriate parameters to make a GET request (you will presumably have to do an OAuth2 authentication first to get a token), and send the output to a local destination specified in "Output File URL." Then you can use a `FlatFileReader` to read from that local file.

Answer (score 0):

GCS has several different ways to download files from your buckets. You can use the console and the Cloud Storage browser. Steps: open the storage browser, navigate to the object you want to download, right click, and save to your chosen local folder. If you use Chrome the save appears as “Save Link As…”.

To use the GS Utility, use this command:

```
`gsutil cp gs://[BucketName]/[ObjectName] [ObjectDestination]`.
```

Or you can use client libraries or the REST APIs to download files. With these last options you could work with a number of files or create a job to download them. Once they are in a location known to Clover ETL the process is straightforward.

Within Clover designer, under the navigation pane you can right click a folder and choose import.  Pick the one in which you placed your GCS file. Once the file is imported then you can use data from it like any other datafile in Clover.  Since this is a .csv file, remember to edit your metadata (right click the component, choose extract metadata then edit inside the Metadata Editor -- for data types, labels and such.) Assign metadata to the edges of your components so they know what is coming in/going out of that step. Depending on your file, this process may be repeated many times.

Even with an ETL tool, getting the data and data types correct can be tricky. If you have questions about how to configure data types or your edges in an ETL project, a wiki may help. The web has [additional resources](https://www.etltools.net/wiki/) may help you get the end analysis you’re looking for.